# Difference between a subsystem and a component

Tags: uml, modeling

I would like to ask what is the difference between a subsystem and a component in the UML sense?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have to agree with Preet, but practically, a subsystem is larger than a component.  I use components for libraries (either bought, pillaged, or built) and subsystems for a part of the whole system that performs a given integrated function.  For example, in a blood processing device, the centrifuge driver and control would be a component.  The integrated blood suction regulation (which includes safety mechanisms, motor control, user control, and communications) would be a subsystem.

Comment: I have a question: I am building a C++ SDK and I'm doing some UML. Each of my modules in my SDK are as decoupled as possible but there are dependencies between modules. There is a general purpose software API and a firmware toolkit that depends on the software toolkit. The firmware toolkit is 100% definitely separated from the desktop as subsystems because the dependency is one-way and they are separated conceptually as hardware and software subsystems. Would the SDK modules themselves then be subsystems? Seams to me like the subsystems would then contain packages.

Answer (score 8):

Before UML 2.0 I could perfectly see a `<<subsystem>>` as a design-time `<<component>>`, which would finally become a `<<component>>`. The UML 1.4 defines component as "A modular, **deployable**, and replaceable part of a system that encapsulates implementation and exposes a set of interfaces. A component is typically specified by one or more classifiers (e.g., implementation classes) that reside on it, and may be implemented by one or more artifacts (e.g., binary, executable, or script files)."

After the aforementioned "fuzziness" was introduced to the UML (in UML 2.0), I am more inclined to use `<<subsystem>>` as a larger `<<component>>`, and see both of them as replaceable and reusable constituents of a system.

Answer (score 4):

From [IBM developerWorks - UML basics: The component diagram](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/dec04/bell/)

> The **UML 2 specification is quite vague
>   on how a subsystem is different from a
>   component**. The specification does not
>   treat a component or a subsystem any
>   differently from a modeling
>   perspective. Compared with UML 1.x,
>   this UML 2 modeling ambiguity is new.
>   But there's a reason. In UML 1.x, a
>   subsystem was considered a package,
>   and this package notation was
>   confusing to many UML practitioners;
>   hence UML 2 aligned subsystems as a
>   specialized component, since this is
>   how most UML 1.x users understood it.
>   This change did introduce fuzziness
>   into the picture, but this fuzziness
>   is more of a reflection of reality
>   versus a mistake in the UML 2
>   specification.

So in short *none*.

Answer (score 2):

In UML models, subsystems are a type of stereotyped component that represent independent, behavioral units in a system. Subsystems are used in class, component, and use-case diagrams to represent large-scale components in the system that you are modeling.

You can model an entire system as a hierarchy of subsystems. You can also define the behavior that each subsystem represents by specifying interfaces to the subsystems and the operations that support the interfaces.

In diagrams, compartments display information about the attributes, operations, provided interfaces, required interfaces, realizations, and internal structure of the subsystem.

Typically, a subsystem has a name that describes its contents and role in the system.

As the following figure illustrates, a subsystem is displayed as a rectangle that contains the name of the subsystem. It also contains the keyword «Subsystem» and the subsystem icon.

From: [IBM Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS8PJ7_9.6.0/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/csubsys.html)